# Why vagrant claim about Powershell version (minimum 3)?

Tags: windows-10, vagrant, chocolatey, powershell-5.0

Trying to use Vagrant and it claims about Powershell minimum version 3 installed.
I have Windows 10 Pro and Vagrant 2.2.16 and the minimum version at Windows 10 is 5.
Tried to use chocolatey and install latest version and the standlone version 7.1.3 and still continue with this issue.

Can't figure out what should I do. Have reinstalled Vagrant, upgrade powershell with:

```
choco install powershell
```

And installed the standalone version 7.1.3 and not solved this issue.
[image]

Comment: Check the environment PATH to see if `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` is included. You might need to reboot.

Comment: @harrymc Tks, will do later!

Comment: Of course *%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0* is going to be include in the author’s PATH variable.  The real question is the path to PowerShell 7.1 going to be include BEFORE that path.  This appears to be a Vagrant compatibility issue with PowerShell Core 7.1 more than anything.  It’s also possible chocolatey is really confused.  PowerShell 7.1 Core command prompt != PowerShell 5.1 prompt

Comment: Post the chocolatey log